# Time dependent updating collection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to update my mongoose document's field if that document's other field is has expired time.

*For example:*
Update HotelRoom model's status if guests checkout time.

I have 2 ideas about this.

- In app.js with setInterval() using mongodb's updateMany function

```
// app.js
setInterval(() => {
  //
}, 1000)
```

- At mongoose post hook as an async function using without awaiting for setTimeout function.

```
// Room.js

roomSchema.post('save', async (err, doc) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // 
  }, 60 * 60 * 60)
})
```

**So question is:** What is best practice to do this or any ideas? Thanx ❤️

> I don't want to use mongoose expires (I mean I don't want to delete document)

Comment: I don't know if that is a good idea, but you could make an extra object in the database which gets a postexpire hook triggering a reset on the status of the referenced room document

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with setting up a timer in memeory (using `setTimeout()`) is that if the app or the server needs to restart (as a result of crashing or needing to be updated), the jobs in the the timer queue will be lost. Statuses will not be updated when they need to be, and your DB will be holding out of date information.

Instead of trying to set up functionality to update the status of the Room in the background whenever it’s time for a user to checkout, you could use a mongoose [virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) to work out the status of the room at read time. This will calculate the correct value on the fly and mean there's no uneccassary background work going on – and you'll never have out of date values in the DB.

> Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do not get persisted to MongoDB

The `status` property is never actually saved to the Mongo Database (So you would not see it if you were viewing a room document in MongoDB Compass GUI).

You would set this up in the room schema:

```
// Room.js
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    checkoutTime: {
        type:  Number // using a unix epoch timestamp here for simplicity
    }
});

roomSchema.virtual('status').get(function calculateRoomStatus() {
    if (Date.now() > this.checkoutTime) { // if the checkout time is in the past...
        return 'Vacant';
    } else {
        return 'Occupied';
    }
});
```

Mongoose calls the `calculateRoomStatus()` function every time the `status` property is accessed. The return value of the function call is given as the value of `status`.

Inside the virtual's getter function `this` refers to the document being queried, so in this case the Room document.

Using a virtual has a major drawback: because the status is not stored in the DB you cannot use it in queries. Consequently when searching for vacant rooms, instead of searching using `status`, you would need to search for rooms with a checkout date in the past:

```
// To search for vacant rooms
const vacantRooms = await Room.find({
    checkoutTime: { $lt: Date.now() }
}).exec();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Billy. It was so helpful  